# What questions should I ask as a candidate during interview for a PhD program that assigns you an advisor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, interview, psychology

*I'm applying for Psychology PhD.

There's a university that I am applying to but unlike some of the other universities I've found, where students can state their desired advisor, this university accepts students based on a collective decision and assigns you an initial advisor.

There were articles and questions on what to ask during PhD interviews, but not many for programs that do not give you the freedom of pick and choosing the lab you wish to work in.

What are some good questions to ask during the interview for a program that does not give you this option?
Since it's the collective department accepting you, are there any useful ways to spot potential 'red flags'?

Thank you in advance to those who read and answer this question

Comment: They assign you an initial advisor.  So you can change advisors? Perhaps the initial advisor is just a formality.  Anyway if you want to work with Professor X, why not just ask "Can I work with Professor X?"

Comment: Read the department materials (e.g. how does one go about switching advisors), and take a good look at the current research interests there.  Mark things you'd like to ask more about, or gaps in what is available on their website.

Comment: How does "choose an advisor" even work? Certainly there has to be agreement from both sides?